# Not exists statement when trying to select a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert a row and prevent duplication. I used `not exists` to do the filtering. However, the results always contain the ones I don't need. My question is how to select rows that data from all column match?

for example:

```
insert into TB1 (Id, Name) VALUES (1, 'Job')
insert into TB1 (Id, Name) VALUES (2, 'Bob')
insert into TB1 (Id, Name) VALUES (3, 'Cob')

insert into TB2 (Id, Name) VALUES (1, 'Fob')
insert into TB2 (Id, Name) VALUES (2, 'Bob')
insert into TB2 (Id, Name) VALUES (3, 'Job')
insert into TB2 (Id, Name) VALUES (4, 'Mob')


select b.Id, b.Name
from TB2 as b
where not exists 
(
    select 1
    FROM TB1 as a
    where a.Id = b.Id and
    a.Name = B.Name
)
```

Here, the return is going to be: 1, fob; 3, job; 4, mob.
Though my intention was only to get 4.mob, as 4.mob is the one not in table 1.

Comment: no it would check if **any** other row thatis not  the exact equal exists, as 2 Bob is identical in both tables it will be not returned

Comment: You are  correlating on both Id and Name though, so the result you get are correct, those *combinations* don't exist - if it's only the Id you care about then only correlate the Id, likewise Name.

Comment: What if I need them to be a pair, this is just a bad example. like a name and job, a many-to-many relationship

Comment: It seems like your requirement then is `where a.Id = b.Id OR a.Name = B.Name`

Comment: Or two perhaps separate `not exists` conditions, one checking for name and one checking for id, if your data sets are large and you would like top optimize index usage.

Comment: Thank @Stu, OR made it work, which is kinda odd since I was asking for condition a And condition b to be true.

Comment: No that's not what you wanted, eg you are not expecting `1. Fob`  but `1` *AND* `Fob` does not exist, so that's *true*

Comment: @Slowcode_beef If you want a better example with `Name` and `Job` then edit your question to supply one. You'll likely find that `where TB1.Name = TB2.Name and TB1.Job = TB2.Job` is the correct condition. `Id` isn't involved

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways:

**Using `EXCEPT`**

```
SELECT Id FROM TB2 EXCEPT ALL SELECT Id FROM TB1
```

**Using `NOT EXIST`**

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM TB2 A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM TB1 WHERE Id=A.Id)
```

**Using `LEFT JOIN`**

```
select A.Id,A.Name FROM TB2 A LEFT JOIN TB1 B USING(Id) WHERE B.Id IS NULL
```

**Using `NOT IN`**

However, the best way to prevent duplicates would be to add a unique index on ID and to use `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY`.

Comment: Sorry, I think I wrote a really bad example, I meant to ask if there are multiple columns (not including the id) as part of a batch insertion being inserted, how do I prevent dups, as there could be many combinations in a many-to-many situation?

Comment: @Slowcode_beef If you over-simplify your question and effectively make it a different problem, you're going to get answers to a different problem.